# How to register DLL from .bat file in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

As part of a poor-mans installation (on Windows 7) I need to register a DLL from a .bat file. I provide the user with a set of files that make up the application, tell them to copy them to some (any) directory,  then, as the 1st part of the install, tell them to execute my register.bat file which invokes regsvr32 on the appropriate DLL(s)

This fails with 0x80004005 (permission) error. I then try running the .bat file as an Admin. This doesn't work as it opens the command prompt in \windows\system32 which is not where the DLLs to be registered are located. As I don't know where the user has placed the register.bat file I can't put the path to the DLL files in the .bat file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just do it right and create an installer?  This sounds like 15 minutes worth of work to me. Longer if you don't know anything about installers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `%~dp0` to get the folder the batch file is stored in, like:

```
regsvr32 %~dp0\mylibrary.dll
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick ... thanks. Have never heard of the %~dp0 magic. Also, where is the blessed place on a windows machine to place application-specific DLLs? C:\, \WIndows, \windows\system32 ?

Comment: I'd put them in your application folder; shared folders are for shared DLL's, like runtimes and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can get and use the path of the current directory like this:

```
set "FullPath=%cd%\Test.dll"
```